# MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile() is throwing java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I HAVE ENSURED THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION (eliasah!)

I trying to read in a LibSVMFile which is in the correct format.

```
The following code 'MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "testdata.txt")' is throwing java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
```

It is failing on the first line of the input file. The first line is this:

```
1 128:51 129:159 130:253 131:159 132:50 155:48 156:238 157:252 158:252 159:252 ....
```

I have looked at the following links and they do not address the issue:
[How can I read LIBSVM models (saved using LIBSVM) into PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872776/how-can-i-read-libsvm-models-saved-using-libsvm-into-pyspark)
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/MLLib-LIBSVM-issue-td14507.html

Comment: Hi Winston! Welcome to StackOverflow. If you think it's not a duplicate, try to edit your previous question to make the problem look different. Provide a [mcve] for us to work with otherwise this will flagged as off-topic. In your current state, it's very difficult to tell what the current problem is. Please format the question as well. Thanks.

Comment: If I don't think it's a dup, then what would you like me to say in the question? It isn't a dup of a previous question, so I'm not sure what you guys would like me to edit.